# File name contains % sign due to that unable to download

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

**Explanation :**

For example I have uploaded file on my website with that name `15-00070_10% IMG-7837_11272015_1_1.pdf` which I have bound in anchor tag as below

```
<a style="color:#2a6496;text-decoration:underline;" href="/TransactionDocuments/C0001/15-00070_10% IMG-7837_11272015_1_1.pdf" target="_blank" download="">10% IMG-7837.pdf</a>
```

so I am getting error as below error.

> Failed - server problem

If anyone have any idea about it than please let me know.

Comment: Did you try to [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp)?

Comment: Then remove `%` character from file name. You should use `POSIX` Fully portable filename characters in your file names i.e. `A–Z a–z 0–9 . _ -`

Comment: replace the character before upload

Answer (score 1):

Use [URL encoding](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).

Your filename encoded is `15-00070_10%25%20IMG-7837_11272015_1_1.pdf`